# Powershell regex to return a part of a line after finding a value on a previous line

Tags: regex, powershell, jks

I'm trying to audit certificate expiry and I want to grab the expiry date of a specific certificate from a Java keystore.

The certificate order potentially could change so i need to get the expiry line *after* a particular keystore alias.

Example keystore:

```
Keystore type: jks
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 2 entries

Alias name: one
Creation date: Apr 25, 2010
Entry type: keyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=host.domain.com, OU=Application Development, O=devdaily.com, L=Louisville, ST=KY, C=US
Issuer: CN=Alvin Alexander, OU=Application Development, O=devdaily.com, L=Louisville, ST=KY, C=US
Serial number: 4bd4e793
Valid from: Mon Apr 25 17:08:35 AKDT 2017 until: Mon Jul 24 17:08:35 AKDT 2019
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  55:20:B2:68:FD:0F:4E:BF:D5:E5:D5:04:47:6C:E3:10
     SHA1: 25:17:A0:CA:86:CC:3E:6C:2D:C0:4E:8D:E8:33:05:F7:4B:50:FE:E5

*******************************************
*******************************************

Alias name: two
Creation date: Apr 25, 2015
Entry type: keyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=Alvin Alexander, OU=Application Development, O=devdaily.com, L=Louisville, ST=KY, C=US
Issuer: CN=Alvin Alexander, OU=Application Development, O=devdaily.com, L=Louisville, ST=KY, C=US
Serial number: 4bd4e793
Valid from: Tues Apr 25 17:08:35 AKDT 2010 until: Tues Jul 24 17:08:35 AKDT 2025
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  55:20:B2:68:FD:0F:4E:BF:D5:E5:D5:04:47:6C:E3:10
     SHA1: 25:17:A0:CA:86:CC:3E:6C:2D:C0:4E:8D:E8:33:05:F7:4B:50:FE:E5

*******************************************
*******************************************


Alias name: three
Creation date: Apr 25, 2010
Entry type: keyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=host.domain.com, OU=Application Development, O=devdaily.com, L=Louisville, ST=KY, C=US
Issuer: CN=Alvin Alexander, OU=Application Development, O=devdaily.com, L=Louisville, ST=KY, C=US
Serial number: 4bd4e793
Valid from: Wed Apr 25 17:08:35 AKDT 2030 until: Wed Jul 24 17:08:35 AKDT 2035
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  55:20:B2:68:FD:0F:4E:BF:D5:E5:D5:04:47:6C:E3:10
     SHA1: 25:17:A0:CA:86:CC:3E:6C:2D:C0:4E:8D:E8:33:05:F7:4B:50:FE:E5

*******************************************
*******************************************
```

So I'd like to return `"Wed Jul 24 17:08:35 AKDT 2035"` from certificate 'three'.

Essentially the regex needs to return the data after 'until:' on the 'Valid from:' line after it sees the certificate alias: 'three'

I'm doing this with powershell and I have the following:

```
(?<=three)(?:.*?)(?:Until:\s)(\s*.*)
```

The above fails as I'm trying to positively lookbehind on a different line. If I lookbehind on the same line it works:

```
(?<=Wed)(?:.*?)(?:Until:\s)(\s*.*)
```

I've looked at this for a few hours but I can't figure it out!

Comment: see [this](https://regex101.com/r/AnL4rw/2),you need just get group 1 with `$1`

Comment: and for some line [demo](https://regex101.com/r/AnL4rw/3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an other approach using `Select-String` with the `context` parameter :

```
$c = Get-Content c:\temp\certs.txt
$three = $c |Select-String "alias name: three" -Context 8
$expirity = [regex]::Match($three.Context.DisplayPostContext[7],"until:(.*)").value.split(':')[1]
```

Comment: Thanks Loic, that was really helpful!

Comment: I ended up modifying the regex slightly so I could return the entire string (the 2018) was missing from the end. $expirity = [regex]::Match($three.Context.DisplayPostContext[7],"(?<=until:\s)(\s*.*)"). No need for the split. Thanks for the very quick reponse!